# Try to make circuit with problem

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[R=$R_B$] ++(0,2) coordinate(a)
        -- ++(0,1) node[op amp, anchor=+](A){}
        (a) to[R=$R_A$, *-] (a-|A.out) -- (A.out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I try to make this but I have problems sorry for my English can anyone help

[image: 131]

Comment: welcome to the site -- have a look at the answer below -- a circuit in a box that can be repeatedly used as well as independently

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592878/38080 ?

Comment: It may help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379911/how-to-draw-an-electric-circuit-with-the-help-of-circuitikz/379915#379915

Comment: @Amir would you like to accept and upvote the answer below if it met the requirement

Answer (score 2):

Source--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592731/38080

**Circuit in a box**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\newsavebox{\mycirc}
\sbox{\mycirc}{% no stray spaces
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[R=$R_B$] ++(0,2) coordinate(a)
        -- ++(0,1) node[op amp, anchor=-, yscale=-1](A){}
        (a) to[R=$R_A$, *-] (a-|A.out) -- (A.out);
        \draw(A.out)to[short, -o,]++(1,0)node[above]{$V_{out}$}; 
        \draw(A.+)to[short, -o,]++(-1,0)node[above]{$V_{in}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}% no stray spaces
}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \node [draw, text width=3cm, align=center]{% no stray spaces
            \adjustbox{width=3cm, height=3cm, keepaspectratio}{\usebox{\mycirc}}%
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Independent use**

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[R=$R_B$] ++(0,2) coordinate(a)
    -- ++(0,1) node[op amp, anchor=-, yscale=-1](A){}
    (a) to[R=$R_A$, *-] (a-|A.out) -- (A.out);
    \draw(A.out)to[short, -o,]++(1,0)node[above]{$V_{out}$}; 
    \draw(A.+)to[short, -o,]++(-1,0)node[above]{$V_{in}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT for Bill Nace query

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[R=$R_B$] ++(0,2) coordinate(a)
        -- ++(0,1) node[op amp, anchor=-, yscale=-1](A){}
        (a) to[R=$R_A$, *-] (a-|A.out)coordinate[label={}](b) ;
        \draw(A.out)coordinate[ label=](c)to[short, -o,]++(1,0)node[above]{$V_{out}$}; 
        \draw(A.+)to[short, -o,]++(-1,0)node[above]{$V_{in}$};
        \draw[<-, red, in=180, out=-45](b) to ++(2,-2)node[right](){\scriptsize (a) {\texttt {-|}}  (A.out)};
        \draw[circle,fill= green](c)circle(1pt);
        \draw[circle,fill= red](b)circle(1pt);
        \draw [<-, green, in=180, out=-45](c) to ++(2,-2)node[right](){\scriptsize (A.out)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please cite the source when reusing code --- in this case mine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592731/38080 but in general (it's required by the site license). Thanks!

Comment: done -oversight on my part

Comment: Why must you draw from (a) to the intersection location and then up to (A.out)?  Why doesn't the -| notation work as in (a) to[R=$R_A#, *-] -| (A.out)   ?

Comment: @BillNace so it works like this -- draw an imaginary horizontal line right from `coordinate a` and also draw an imaginary line downwards from `A.out` -- the intersection of these lines provides the end point of the circuit from `R_A` -- to complete the circuit you still need to draw a physical wire from the intersection of the 2 imaginary lines up to connect to `A.out`

Comment: @BillNace  have a look at the edit above

Comment: @BillNace because the syntax is `(coord) to[] (coord)`  to draw an element. What you say it's not correct because `|-` is already a path element; it would be like saying `(coord) to[element] to[vertical and horizontal wire] (coord)` so Tikz does not know the intermediate point.

Comment: Thank you all, that's very helpful and illuminating.